# OnKeyUp event with timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery is kind of new to me and I set up a search suggestions system using ajax that works great but works pretty slow due to the onKeyUp limitation.  After some reading I found that I can set a timer on the event. So what I am trying to do is set a timer on the 'prod-name-input' input field onKeyUp event, so that it is called every 2 seconds. I found a few examples for this online, but I wasn't able to apply any of them to my code successfully, I was wondering if someone can walk me through how this works? many thanks in advance.

My input field

```
<input onKeyUp="search(this.value)" type="text" class="prod-name-input"/>
```

JS

```
function search(searchword) {
        $('.smart-suggestions').load('invoice-get-data.php?searchword=' + searchword);  
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest way would actually be to use the keydown event. (it acts on the key being down rather than being released which is always sooner.)

```
var timer;
$(".prod-name-input").keydown(function(){
    var self = this;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $(".smart-suggestions").load('invoice-get-data.php?searchword=' + self.value);
    },250);
});
```

This loads results if the user stops typing for more than 1/4 of a second. If too many requests are happening, increase the delay to 500.

I'll go over the code line by line with comments:

```
// declare a variable that will hold a reference to the timer we create
var timer;
// bind a keydown event to all existing elements that have the prod-name-input class
$(".prod-name-input").keydown(function(){
    // store a reference to the clicked element so we can access it inside of setTimeout()
    var self = this;
    // clear existing timer stored in the timer variable (if any)
    clearTimeout(timer);
    // create a new timer and store it in the timer variable
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        // load content
        $(".smart-suggestions").load('invoice-get-data.php?searchword=' + self.value);
    // give the timer a 250ms delay (0.25 seconds or 1/4 of a second)
    },250);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a throttle function in underscore.js that handles this scenario. You can see their [annotated source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-62) for exact code, or if you use underscore.js in your project, some usage documentation [here](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle)